# PHP Printing the actual Function name to screen

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I am learning PHP for an interview. I have never coded in PHP and have spent about 3 days doing exercises, Now I am trying to create a simple form that connects to a MySQL Database.

I created a User Class and db Class.

When I try to call the method to connect to the Database from my db class it literally prints what I called to the screen. (See image below)
[image]

below is the HTML for the form and php. The other pasted php is from an external class file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/a4e256ed67403c6ad5d43937ed48a77b?family=Core+Sans+N+W01+35+Light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BattleNET_Form_Style.css" type="text/css">

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>         

<?php
    require "./Classes/Users.php";
    require "./Classes/db.php";
    session_start();
   $_SESSION['message'] = '';
   $db = new db();
    if($db->ConnectToDatabase() == true){
      $stuff = "yarp";
    }
?>


<div class="body-content">

<div class="module">

    <h1>Create an account</h1>
    <!-- Dont forget, POST means you are not sending the data in the URL. In this instance we are gonna have the form submit to itself. -->
    <form class="form" action="BattleNET_Form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

        <!-- Display the session messages in the div we created for said errors. -->
        <div class="alert alert-error"><?= $_SESSION['message'];?></div>

        <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="username" required />
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password" required />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmpassword" autocomplete="new-password" required />

        <div class="avatar"><label>Select your avatar: </label><input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/*" required /></div>

        <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" />

    </form>

   </div>

</div>
</body>
```

below is the db.php class I have commented out code in the class, just trying to reduce complexity to see if maybe some error inside the db class is causing the error.

```
<?php
    class db
    {
      private $host = 'localhost';
      private $username = 'webUser';
      private $password = 'totalTest';
      private $dbname = 'accounts';
      protected static $connection;
      public function ConnectToDatabase(){
        $result = false;
        return $result;
       }
   }
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

*** EDIT ***

I ensured that the CLI Interpreter and the Version of PHP I am Running on the WAMP Server where correct. See image below.
[image]

Comment: Have you installed PHP? Are the PHP files `.php`? Do you actually use `<?php` tags?

Comment: yes, yes, yes. I orignially was using WAMP and Sublime Text. but switched to phpStorm because I could get it for free for a year with my student ID. I have done some exercises so I atleast know enough to use the php tags, and to know that I have php installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try and remove the last `?>` in the db.php file to avoid issues with whitespaces and alsi remove all comment from both files?

Its a good practice that you do not close the `<?php` at the end of the file if you are not going to write any html at the end.

Also please note that you do not have a the method `__constructor` and still calling the db Class with `new db()`.

You have to either change the method you are calling statically or create the `__constructor` method to the db class

Comment: sorry I double checked and the end tags are not present in my source file, I added them when I edited the post the last time, but to be honest I had no Idea you didn't need the end tags if it were a stand alone class file. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to delete the block of comments you have in db.php.l?  I think the problem is either with comments or whitespaces, since you are not outputting anythingg from db.php

Comment: I just did it. I actually removed all comments from the BattleNET_Form.php and db.php. I also removed all white space between lines in the php tags and files to see if that would have an effect. It had no effect.

Comment: See my updated answer, to make sure everything is as it should

Comment: I changed the method ConnectToDatabase static. Nothing (stupid mistake on my part). Same issue. Thank you very much for your patience. *EDIT* I just closed the webpage and reloaded by navigating to the file, and viola magically gone. I am gonna say out of all the comments I got. I believe me not putting static on the DB call was the problem. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `'` at the following line:

`private $dbname = '`

You should finish this line. Also put a `;` at the end. For example:

`private $dbname = 'database_name';`

Comment: sorry, It is there for what ever reason I must have accidentally deleted it when formatting the code for this post.

Comment: Could you check everything you have copy pasted into here? I'm also missing a `}` at the end of `db.php`. Can you extend the code snippets with some more? Also, Is the HTML surrounded with `<html>` tags and such?

Comment: sorry bout that. Edited.

Comment: 2 things unrelated to the issue: You should add your `link` tags in the head section, and where do you include the php file in your html?

Comment: in the body above the "body-content" div

Comment: You have to include them like this: `<?php require "somefile.php"; ?>`. The same way you include those classes. A link tag is for styling purposes (and some other things)

Comment: when I pasted the code on here, the <?php ?> tags would not show up.

Comment: You have to indent every piece of code. What was exactly there?

Comment: apparently I am dense. I got the php tags to show up now. Is still don't understand why they wouldn't show up the first time. I apologize for that.